# PSDK Windows Server 2003 R2 MFC support

Tags: c++, mfc

First I installed PSDK Windows Server 2003 R2 on my x86 machine, there were MFC header files out there. I tried to compile an example MFC application with cl.exe and I got this error message "winmsg_.h header file could not be opened.". I got "winmsg_.h" file from the International Network and put it into the MFC include files library then I again tried to compile the program and got that target platform option conflicts with IA64 platform specific object file. I think that PSDK Windows Server 2003 R2 does not include lib files for x86 machines!

Please help me to solve this problem or suggest me the PSDK that contains the header and lib files for x86 machines! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Download SDK from Microsoft Website](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3069). It supports both 32 and 64 bit architectures. I'd suggest you to use a make file instead of barely using CL.exe for compilation. You will have to give proper include files to resolve the issues. Which version of the compiler you're using? How you installed it?

Don't go for a third party provided headers. Use the original ones.

Comment: I installed MS Visual C++ 2008 Express edition. The compiler, header and lib files come with it "Not MFC". But I installed PSDK Windows Server 2003 R2 to gain access to MFC header and lib files by adding environment "INCLUDE" and "LIB" variables. My cl.exe compiler is able to compile the MFC applications but not for x86 platform, because there is no lib file for x86 machine in PSDK WinServer 2003 R2. It might be in the PSDK WinServer 2003 SP1, probably! And please tell me some more about makefile! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and people sometimes become upset when you revive a dead post.  That said, Google brought me here, and I'm sure many others will be directed this way.  This is what I, and I believe you, was/ were looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30439/How-to-compile-MFC-code-in-Visual-C-Express

Answer (score 0):

ATL/MFC headers are not on Platofrm/Windows SDK. Instead, they are shipped with Visual Studio (except Express versions).